# Git fetch/pull didn't get all files down

Tags: git, github

I checked out from v3 branch from a repo :
https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/v3

However, it didn't bring down any of the files from the folder:
https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/tree/35d690c54954dc6cebefeef898b7684e41949cfb

However I noticed something different about this particular folder :
[image]
@ commit hash

Any ideas what's the deal with the @ hash ref is and how I get pull the files down?

Comment: Did you check the readme at https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/tree/35d690c54954dc6cebefeef898b7684e41949cfb ? It takes you here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui is a submodule.... 35d690c is the specific commit,
try git pull --recurse-submodules

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything, got "Already up-to-date."

Comment: oh... ok, try git submodule update --init --recursive before of git pull --recurse-submodules

Comment: Thanks, that worked and also learnt something new about GIT sub modules ;)

Comment: I'm happy with that... :D